# SQL - database references

Tags: sql

**Sales** table:

```
id | product_id | year | quantity | price
---+------------+------+----------+-------
 1 |        100 | 2008 |       10 |  5000
 2 |        100 | 2008 |       10 |  5000
 3 |        200 | 2011 |       15 |  9000
```

**Products** table:

```
id | product_name | product_id
---+--------------+------------
 1 | Nokia        |        100
 2 | Apple        |        200
 3 | Samsung      |        200
```

In these two tables, I have references the **Sales** table and the  **Products** table as shown here:

```
CREATE TABLE Sales_table
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    product_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    year INTEGER NOT NULL,
    quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
    price INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Products_table
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    product_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    product_id INTEGER REFERENCES Sales_table
);
```

These two tables are created successfully, but when I insert data into the Products_table, I get an error

> ERROR:  insert or update on table "products_table" violates foreign key constraint "products_table_product_id_fkey"
> DETAIL: Key (product_id)=(200) is not present in table "sales_table".

By the mean of, the referenced table doesn't allow same 'product_id' field name means, then why the Products_table table has been created with the REFERENCES of Sales_table?

Comment: That is **NOT** SQL Server code - tag removed - please add the **actual RDBMS** you're using as a tag !

Comment: That because the column `id` in `Sales_table` is referenced by `Products_table` and the `product_id` you enter doesn't exists in `Sales_table`

Answer (score 0):

Your foreign key references are backwards.  You want:

```
 CREATE TABLE Products_table (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   product_name VARCHAR NOT NULL
 );

CREATE TABLE Sales_table (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   product_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   year INTEGER NOT NULL,
   quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
   price INTEGER NOT NULL,
   product_id INTEGER REFERENCES product_table (id)
 );
```

I actually advise naming the primary key after the table -- so primary key and foreign key column names match (i.e. `JOIN`s with `USING` make sense).  Also, in more recent versions of Postgres, `generated always as identity` is preferred over `serial`.  So:

```
 CREATE TABLE Products_table (
   product_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   product_name VARCHAR NOT NULL
 );

CREATE TABLE Sales_table (
   sale_id GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   product_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   year INTEGER NOT NULL,
   quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
   price INTEGER NOT NULL,
   product_id INTEGER REFERENCES products_table (product_id)
 );
```